# react-data-grid-addons: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-data-grid

I'm using react-data-grid-addons with react. When i run my project after installed this, I get an error and some other in react-data-grid-addons.js

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

```
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

'use strict';

exports.__esModule = true;
exports.SimpleRowsContainer = undefined;

var _react = __webpack_require__(2);

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _propTypes = __webpack_require__(3);

var _propTypes2 = _interopRequireDefault(_propTypes);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

...

  return RowsContainer;
}(_react2['default'].Component); // Error on this line.
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The build is not able to find **Component** which you might have forgot to import in your code. The following code must fix the same.

import {Component} from 'react'